# Interactive chart is not working for the below shiny code, unable to visualize selected companies Ex:apple and microsoft

Tags: r, shiny

Shiny interactivity is not working, the graph shows all the companies together, I need just selected companies. Example: Apple and Microsoft, or Apple, Microsoft and Google.

**Current output:**

[image: Current output]

DATA columns = date, close_price, company

```
#Uploading data in R
library(shiny)
library(data.table)
library(ggmap)

#Changing date format
stock$date <- as.Date(stock$date, format = "%d/%m/%Y")


#Setting up Shiny
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("companys in stock"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      uiOutput("companyOutput"),
      uiOutput("close_price"),
      uiOutput("dateOutput")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("spatial_plot")
      
    )
  )
)

#check box's of company 
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$companyOutput <- renderUI({
    checkboxGroupInput("companyInput", "company",
                       sort(unique(stock$company)),
                       selected = "Apple")
  })
  
  #date range
  output$dateOutput <- renderUI({
    dateRangeInput("date", label = "Date range", start = "2000-01-01", 
                   end = "2017-07-31")
  })
  
  filtered <- reactive({
    if (is.null(input$companyInput)) {
      return(NULL)
    }    
    
    stock %>%
      filter( company == input$companyInput,
              date >=input$date[1] & date <=input$date[2])
    
  })
  #spatial plots
  output$spatial_plot <- renderPlot({
    if (is.null(filtered())) {
      return()
    }
    

    
   ggplot(data =stock,aes(x=date,y=close_price,color=company))+geom_line(stat = "identity")+
     xlab('Date')+ylab('Closing Price')+
     ggtitle('Share Performances of stock 4 Comapnies')
    
    
  })
  

}
#shiny ui& server
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

**Code to remake the dataset:**

```
stock <- structure(list(date = c("03/01/2000", "04/01/2000", "05/01/2000", 
"06/01/2000", "07/01/2000", "10/01/2000"), code = c("AAPL", "AAPL", 
"AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL"), close_price = c(3.997768, 3.660714, 
3.714286, 3.392857, 3.553571, 3.491071), company = c("Apple", 
"Apple", "Apple", "Apple", "Apple", "Apple")), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems in your code:

- the conditions in `filtered()` aren't good
- you call `stock` instead of `filtered()` in `ggplot()` (this is why it showed all the companies and not only the ones you selected)
- you shouldn't use `uiOutput()` and `renderUI()` if possible, it slows down the app
- you can use `req()` instead of `if` conditions with `NULL`

I voluntarily replaced `Apple` by `Google` sometimes in your data so that you can see that the app works.

Here's the corrected code:

```
#Uploading data in R
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(ggmap)

stock <-
  structure(
    list(
      date = c(
        "03/01/2000",
        "04/01/2000",
        "05/01/2000",
        "06/01/2000",
        "07/01/2000",
        "10/01/2000"
      ),
      code = c("AAPL", "AAPL",
               "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL"),
      close_price = c(3.997768, 3.660714,
                      3.714286, 3.392857, 3.553571, 3.491071),
      company = c("Apple", "Apple", "Google", "Apple", "Google", "Google")
    ),
    row.names = c(NA,
                  6L),
    class = "data.frame"
  )


#Changing date format
stock$date <- as.Date(stock$date, format = "%d/%m/%Y")


#Setting up Shiny
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("companys in stock"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      checkboxGroupInput("companyInput", "company",
                         sort(unique(stock$company)),
                         selected = "Apple"),
      dateRangeInput("date", label = "Date range", start = "2000-01-01", 
                     end = "2017-07-31")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("spatial_plot")
    )
  )
)

#check box's of company 
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  filtered <- reactive({
    req(input$companyInput)
    
    stock %>%
      filter(company %in% input$companyInput &
             date >=input$date[1] & date <=input$date[2])
    
  })

  output$spatial_plot <- renderPlot({
    req(filtered())
  
    ggplot(data = filtered(), aes(x = date, y = close_price, color = company)) +
      geom_line(stat = "identity") +
      xlab('Date') +
      ylab('Closing Price') +
      ggtitle('Share Performances of stock 4 Comapnies')
    
  })
  
}
#shiny ui& server
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thank you sir. you are awesome @bretauv. i am learning Rstudio sir its been just 4 days. i have tried myself and what ever i have written in the code is collected knowledge from internet. Thank you so much for your help and correcting me@bretauv